# Sigma Summation in Excel

Tags: excel

I am looking for some advice on how to do a Sigma calculation in Excel. I have quite an elaborate equation that calculates rebate percentages on casino bets. I'm able to calculate the equation for one round of betting, but when it gets to more than two rounds of betting the equation gets bigger. I have all of the other variables (c, k, P) on the excel sheet, but need to know how to write the formula.
 Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Plz give us some more information, e.g. what is C (number of combinations?) and what value of p you would need to put in to get 4.5076. Also what is the formula you've tried?

Comment: p = 0.493162934500412
C = 100 (to my knowledge)

Comment: Thanks - I get a fairly close answer (4.5062) putting that value in for p and assuming that C means number of combinations selecting k objects from 100 - there may be some issues with accuracy as the calculation involves some very large and small numbers

Comment: I believe the example com the paper is using and displaying rounded figures. What excel formula have you used? I’ve never used these calculations in excel and don’t n ow where to start